# Character doesn't change X axis orientation in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello fellow programmers. I have an issue with my C# script.
I'm making a Unity 2D game, i imported my spritesheet and all, i programmed a way for my character to move on the X axis, it can now walk.
Then i tried to rotate it so it can face the direction he's walking... but it doesn't work, when I make it walk right, it's already facing right so it's fine, but when I make it go left, it just moonwalks to the left.

Here's my code for you to see how I wrote it : (Unity 2022.1.20f1)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class KnightScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float speed = 2f, jumpForce = 500f;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    Animator anim;
    [SerializeField] bool lookRight = true;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        transform.Translate(Vector2.right * move * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        anim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(move));

        if(move < 0 && lookRight)
        {
            Flip();
        }
        else if(move < 0 && lookRight)
        
    }

    void Flip()
    {
        lookRight = !lookRight;
        Vector2 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;

    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: Since this is a `Rigidbody2D` you should not move it in `Update` and through `transform` but rather use [`MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html) in `FixedUpdate` or just simply overwrite its `velocity`

Answer (score 1):

I havent worked with unity for a while now but i think a better appraoch would be to get the Sprite from your GameObject and use the flipX() method like this:

```
GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true;
```

Comment: Dude it works perfectly thank you so much, I almost gone insane but thanks to you the problem is now solved ! :D